# Some modulo hijinkery

Tags: c++, algorithm, modulo

I am solving a question on [LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/minimum-absolute-sum-difference/):

> You are given two positive integer arrays nums1 and nums2, both of length n.The absolute sum difference of arrays nums1 and nums2 is defined as the sum of |nums1[i] - nums2[i]| for each 0 <= i < n (0-indexed). You can replace **at most one element** of nums1 with any other element in nums1 to minimize the absolute sum difference.  Return the *minimum absolute sum difference* after replacing at most one element in the array nums1. Since the answer may be large, return it modulo (10^9 + 7). For Input: `nums1` = `[1,7,5]`, `nums2` = `[2,3,5]`, Output: `3`.

The code that I came up with is as below:

```cpp
class Solution {
public:
    int minAbsoluteSumDiff(vector<int>& nums1, vector<int>& nums2) {
        if(nums1==nums2) return 0;

        long long MOD=(int)1e9+7;

        set<long long> s(begin(nums1),end(nums1));
        
        long long diff=0ll, res=LLONG_MAX;
        for(int i=0; i<nums1.size(); i++)
            diff=(diff%MOD+(abs(nums1[i]-nums2[i]))%MOD)%MOD;
        
        for(int i=0; i<nums2.size(); i++) {
            long long curr=nums2[i];
            auto lb=s.lower_bound(curr);

            if(lb!=s.begin()) {
                auto p=prev(lb);
                long long prevElement=*p;
                long long currsum=diff;

                currsum=(currsum%MOD-(abs(nums1[i]-nums2[i]))%MOD)%MOD;
                currsum=(currsum%MOD+abs(curr-prevElement)%MOD)%MOD;

                res=min(res, currsum);
            }

            if(lb!=s.end()) {
                long long nextElement=*lb;
                long long currsum=diff;

                currsum=(currsum%MOD-(abs(nums1[i]-nums2[i]))%MOD)%MOD;
                currsum=(currsum%MOD+(abs(curr-nextElement))%MOD)%MOD;

                res=min(res, currsum);
            }
        }
        
        return res;
    }
};
```

This works for `50/51` test cases, but on the last one with large values, some modulo hijinkery breaks it.  The reason I do:

```cpp
currsum=(currsum%MOD-(abs(nums1[i]-nums2[i]))%MOD)%MOD;
```

is because of the distributive property of modulo: `(a + b) % c = ((a % c) + (b % c)) % c`.

What am I missing?

Comment: It would be a good idea to hack the code into a [mre]. The question is already collecting down-and-close votes because it isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is a common mistake with modular arithmetic, and surprisingly, has nothing to do with integer overflow (as is usually the case) but is solely the result of **order properties not mixing well with modulus**.

You said the distributive property, `(a + b) % c = ((a % c) + (b % c)) % c`, should let you take moduli inside equations. This stops being true when results are being compared against each other. Let's look at a smaller example with a simpler problem:

```
Given two arrays A and B, find the array with the smallest sum,
 and return its sum modulo 9.

A = [2, 8]
B = [1, 1]
```

Now, the answer should be array B, its sum is 2, which is less than 10. If you only perform modulo at the end, you get the right answer:

```
sum(A) = 10
sum(B) = 2

sum(B) < sum(A), so return (2 % 9) == 2
```

but if you perform modulo in the middle:

```
sum(A) % 9 == 1
sum(B) % 9 == 2

sum(A) % 9 < sum(B) % 9, so you return (1 % 9) == 1
```

Since the constraints here mean your sums can't overflow a long long int, your problem is fixed by **only performing one modulo operation at the very end, inside the return statement**.

In general, problems where you want the (minimum sum) modulo p rather than the minimum (sum modulo p) require you to not perform modular division on intermediate results: you have to use integer types large enough to compare the true value (or at least have a way of comparing true values).

Comment: Great explanation.  Thanks!